# Using my own Objects vs just using a Module

Tags: vb.net, oop

I have read why to use classes, but I don't understand how it makes my program better?

My example: I made a class called "PanelList" and within it are several subs and a few functions that all use related information that will Arrange panels, resizes panels, and Save/Load information from a database. I access it from my main form using:

```
dim myObj as new PanelList()
myObj.Gap = 20
myObj.ArrangePanels(Panel1, Panel2)
```

Why is that better than if I would just do something like this from a module which seems much more condensed and I don't have to create a new instance:

```
ArrangePanels(Panel1, Panel2, 20)
```

I would think creating a new instance of an object would take more resources, and if I need to create several objects it starts to make my code look unorganized in my view?

So why would I use my own Objects??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you describe in your question isn't really object-oriented, so indeed it doesn't sound like it would make much sense to create an object for it.  It's just a helper function that you want to put somewhere.

*Objects* are exactly that... objects.  They are "things" which are described semantically by attributes and operations.  For example, you might have a `Person` object.  It's not just a dumping ground for random functions, but rather a discrete instance representing a "person".  It has data describing that instance of a person, it has operations that can be performed on or by a person, etc.

If you're not doing any object-oriented programming then, no, you don't really need objects.  But if your domain space has discrete semantic concepts of "things" which can be packaged into objects, then it would make sense to do so.

Comment: I kinda of understand, I just don't know when would need to use my own objects. It seems to me the Procedural Programming is what I tend to do, because it just makes sense. I hear the person object and the car objects and even the dog objects, as those make sense in that context they don't make sense to me on when I would need to apply to my own code, if that makes sense? Maybe I should just stick to the procedural programming? any disadvantages to that?

Comment: @goomba454: `"any disadvantages to that?"` - Depends on what you're building.  Some problems naturally have procedural solutions, some naturally have object-oriented solutions, some naturally have functional solutions, etc.  The reason many different tools exist is because no one single tool is suited for all possible problems.

Comment: Ok, that makes me feel a bit better and maybe I worried too much about trying to adhere to the OOP principles when it probably wasn't the right tool for what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm learning as I go and on my own so these conversations are invaluable to me and I appreciate it!